# How to change default timestamp that PHP uses for logging to file?

Tags: php

In the php.ini:

```
error_log = php_errors.log
```

So all `error_log()` calls go into the file `php_errors.log`, every line is prepended by timestamp like `[17-Jan-2012 18:05:04]`.

Is it possible to modify that timestamp? I need to display milli/microseconds as well as seconds and don't know how to do that using standard config options.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own error handler: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: You can check out my custom error logger code: http://pastebin.com/NwDBu86Q Comments are in Latvian, so you'll have to figure it out yourself how it works :) It store logs like this: `/year/month/day.php`

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to prepend by your milisecond / microseconds, but you could append it in option 3 of error_log() in the message parameter.

Comment: I'm using something like this right now. But that's affects only my code unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Apache it appears this may be something controlled by [`mod_log_config`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats).  There is a `LogFormat` directive in your `httpd.conf` that controls the format for error messages.  However, looking through [the docs on `strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) it doesn't appear that milliseconds are possible.

I would likely just [roll-my-own error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php) that controls the timestamp more directly using [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using another web server (written from scratch, specially for out products).